# How to update array element in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have an mongodb document in following format. How to update rolename field of the first element inside an array based on parent property _id.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  abc: [
    {
      roleid: 100,
      rolname: "xyz role"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.collections.updateOne(
  { _id: 1 },
  { $set: { 'abc.$.rolename': 'new value' } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [positional operator (`$`)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "abc.rolname": "xyz role"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "abc.$.rolname": "new rolename"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hW8pO1_Ym5l)